# Stability of dual op-amp Integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, control-system, stability

When we try to analyse the stability of this circuit mentioned [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/454300/understanding-a-dual-op-amp-integrator-circuit), I find that this circuit is unstable.
[image]

It has a zero phase margin. I wanted to know how do we stabilise this circuit for practical implementation?

[image: Stability]

Comment: If you look at the negative feedback path of U2, C1 prevents all DC feedback; so that op-amp will become unstable as the input signal approaches DC (that output will saturate at a power rail.)  But as Andy says, if the input signal never approaches DC (and thus the op-amp output never hits a rail voltage), it will work.  Can you elaborate on the input and output signal details?  Voltage, impedance, frequency, etc.

Comment: The signal does not have DC , it's a quasi square wave of 0.5V.What I am worried about is the significant gain peaking at the vicinity of Transition frequency, because it's here that the phase drops to -180 deg at magnitude of 0dB

Answer (score 2):

If you analysed three cascaded RC low-pass filters (as per those used in phase shift oscillator circuits), the apparent phase margin becomes zero at one particular frequency. It becomes zero at one particular frequency by intention (in order to make the circuit around it oscillate) but, it doesn't mean that the cascaded circuit of three RC low-pass filters is in any way unstable.

I think you may have fallen into the trap of analysing your circuit as being unstable because there is a positive gain at 0° or a phase shift greater than 180° at unity gain.

It's how you use the integrator within a target circuit that might make the target circuit unstable; it's not the integrator itself.

Comment: Can I use this circuit as a standalone integrator ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say this: *standalone integrator* - integrators are never stand-alone because they have massive DC gain and their output will hit the end-stops by just looking at them. They are always used non-stand-alone as far as I'm concerned. Also, the results in your question don't particularly point to a useful characteristic to me (for an integrator).

Comment: @SambeetPanigrahi It's an... integrator. It acts like any integrator would. Instead of analyzing the circuit, stick a Laplace block into any Spice, including CircuitCad on this site, and enter the polynomial of an integrator (\$1/s\$). It will act just like this two op-amp circuit does. See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/615990/10810) for ready-made simulations.

Comment: @Andyaka You can always configure an integrator to have low gain, and be "slow enough" to play with it feeding a signal from a potentiometer that you tweak to keep the integral within bounds... With a human in the loop, the drift is automagically compensated as well :)